# How would I make a paragraph's content change depending on whether an image is loaded or not able to be loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a dashboard for a robot that had an `<img>` tag for loading the webcam off of the robot. I need to make a status indicator (a `<p>` tag) that says online or active if the webcam was successfully loaded and disconnected or unavailable if the webcam was not able to be loaded.

Here is my not working (commented) code:

```html
<div class="topLineView">
        <div class="leftBoxes">
            <div class="firstPersonViewDiv" onload="updateImage();">

                <!-- Old Robot Webcam System
                <img src="http://10.2.54.2:5800/" alt="robot-camera"></img>
                <img id="robot-video" src="http://dreamicus.com/data/image/image-06.jpg" class="firstPersonViewImg" onerror="this.src="2609.jpg" alt="robot-camera"></img>
                -->
                <!-- <script>
                    window.onload = function () {
                        var imageNr = 0;
                        var webcam;

                        function startStream() {
                            webcam = document.getElementById("robot-video");

                            setInterval(renewStream, 2000);
                        }

                        function renewStream() {
                            webcam.src = "http://10.26.9.2:1181/?action=stream" + (++imageNr);
                        }
                    }
                </script> -->
                <img id="robot-video" src="http://10.26.9.2:1181/?action=stream" style="color: red; font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 20px; width: 500px; height: 380px;" class="firstPersonViewImg" alt="Could not connect to robot webcam. Attempting to connect every two seconds...                                           ">
                <!-- Old Robot Video Refresh System
                <script>
                  window.onload = function() {
                    var image = document.getElementById("robot-video");

                    function updateImage(){
                      image.src = image.src.split("?")[0] + "?" + new Date().getTime();
                    }
                    setInterval(updateImage, 500);
                  }
                </script>
                -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Well, what happens when the webcam is not responding.  Does it return an invalid image/location?

Comment: hello zandercraft! Here in stackoverflow we can help you best, if you show us what you already tried.

Comment: Hi Zandercraft Can you show us your code where you are loading the webcam etc?

Comment: Sure @Sarah. I will send it.

Comment: @Zandercraft update question and show your code

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I did...

Comment: @Zandercraft the commented code by "Old Robot..." can be used by us?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Im not sure what you would use it for... But it is the way that I attempted to run the robot's webcam with... It didn't work out properly.... If you want me to remove it from the question, I will.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
let errSimulation=0;

function freshImageUrl() {  
  errSimulation++; if(!(errSimulation%4)) return "zz"; // remove this line

  var baseUrl="http://lorempixel.com/400/200?action=stream&";  
  return `${baseUrl}v=${+new Date}`;  // e.g.  http://...v=1549616957345
}

function refresh(pauseTime) {   
    setTimeout(()=> {
      document.querySelector(".status").innerText="Active";
      document.querySelector("#robot-video").src=freshImageUrl();      
    },pauseTime);
}

function loadErr(e) {   
    document.querySelector(".status").innerText="Unavailable"
    document.querySelector("#robot-video").alt = "Could not connect to robot webcam. Attempting to connect every two seconds...";
    refresh(2000);
}

setTimeout(refresh, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="topLineView">
    <p class="status">Conneting...</p>
    <div class="leftBoxes">
        <div class="firstPersonViewDiv" onload="updateImage();">

            <img onerror="loadErr()" onload="refresh(1000)" id="robot-video" style="color: red; font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 20px; width: 500px; height: 380px;" class="firstPersonViewImg">

        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

The freshImageUrl() contains baseUrl (you shoud change it to: `http://10.26.9.2:1181/?action=stream&`) and generate link to image with additional parameter "v=unixTimestamp" which prevent browser to cache image and always reload it again. The `pauseTime` in `refresh` means additional waiting before next image loading (in miliseconds).

Comment: How does this solution detect whether the connecting to the camera was successful?

Comment: OP ask about status indicator <p>

Comment: "... depending on whether an image is loaded or not able to be loaded"

Comment: the title clarify what he ask about - I understand that he ask about <p> - not whole cam detection

Comment: All this example does is replace the text in a paragraph to "Connected" unconditionally. I think the OP wants it to be replaced with "Unavailable" if the cam didn't connect.

Comment: @marekful I only show the way (by example) to change paragraph content, he can change it however he wants

Comment: @marekful Yes. That is what I wanted. Kamil Kielczewski I was looking for something actually function that detects if the image is loaded then changes the paragraph based on it, not how to change a paragraph's content only.

Comment: Okay... So this seems to be a fixed refresh system. Thanks for that, but what about the webcam status indicator?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Even as a webcam refresh system, it doesn't appear to work... But thanks for trying. I get an error in debug console: SCRIPT12029: SCRIPT12029: WebSocket Error: Network Error 12029, A connection with the server could not be established

Comment: @Zandercraft Answer updated. I based my answer (and idea of refresh img) on code  which you provide in question and as you can see it works. However may be you have other problem with your server/server_connection - this is separate question - you can ask it on StackOverflow

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Thanks for giving me a robot refresh system. But I was looking for a system to change a paragraph depending on the status of the image. There is no networking problem, its just that the ?v=129847972364021 (I just randomly typed those numbers for the example) added onto the end makes it an invalid url because the webcam is not located there.

Comment: @Zandercraft this postfix v=xxx is additional parameter which prevent browser cacheing - it usually works because servers just ignore parameter which are unknown. However if your server not ignore it - create new question on stackoverflow which describe in details this problem (used server technology, examples of working links and non working links (with ?v=xxx or &v=xxx parameters)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Hey... I honestly have no clue why it isnt working. I made a pastebin of the whole document at https://pastebin.com/zW10c76R maybe that will help you.

Comment: @Zandercraft this is separate question (finding bug in your code)  create new question in stackoverflow [in this way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/860099)